# Shift entire recurring series X days ahead

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Suppose I have a recurring meeting with someone, weekly at Wednesday 11:00.

Sometimes I need to reschedule, and the next free time is Sunday, for example.

In that case, I would want to "shift over" the entire future series of appointments N days ahead. Otherwise, I end up with two appointments in the same series following day by day.

How is it possible? One option I've found is to change the recurrence settings for the series, and by that reschedule all meetings. Not very nice.

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, Outlook doesn't provide an option to only modify the future meetings in a recurring meeting. You may consider to modify the "End by" date of the current recurring meeting, and then schedule a new one like introduced in this article: [Cancel all future meetings in a series](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/cancel-all-future-meetings-in-a-series-9eaeee8c-bfe3-46a0-a092-9a2707f3b133)